# Файлы vs база данных для мессенджера

Tags: база-данных

В чем лучше будет хранить переписку с учетом того, что если пользователь online нужно каждую секунду проверять обновился ли чат или нет. Т.е. для файла достаточно смотреть дату обновления. В базу нужно 1 раз в секунду посылать запрос. В каком случае будет меньше нагрузка на сервер? Предполагаемая нагрузка 500-1000 пользователей одновременно.

Comment: По-моему, тут вообще нет предмета для обсуждения. БД. Просто подумай о том, что проверка, обновился чат или нет - это ни фига не единственная операция.

Comment: Запрос новых сообщений, если нет, то нет. если есть, то их подгружаем. AJAX

Comment: А реализовать оба варианта не хорошая практика? Проверить самому почувствовать разницу. Вы думаете можно стать программистом только следуя советам бывалых

Comment: *если есть, то их подгружаем. AJAX* Ага... из текстового файла... многомегабайтного...

Comment: SplFileObject. Держим постоянное соединение и подгружаем сколько нужно (1 запись одна строка). Новые сообщения добавляем в начало. SplFileObject позволяет навигацию. В любом случае выборка будет последовательная.

2 Aziz Umarov. Я думаю это не очень хорошая идея сделать проект, который не будет выдерживать нагрузку и придется переделывать. И не просто переделывать, но еще все конвертить.